# Save and Load VB Windows Forms from SQL Developer Database

Tags: sql, windows-forms-designer

I am developing a D&D Style Tabletop Game with a Digital Interface. Character Sheet, Dice Roller, Reference Guides, Vendors, all at your fingertips... Hopefully... I am writing said interface, attempting anyway, in Visual Studio 2022, Visual Basic Windows Form. I know less about C# than I do VB, to answer that question.

I'm trying to load mine VB Windows Form to mine SQL Developer Database and Call it from another VB Windows Form. Mine knowledge of SQL is worse than C#, lol. I'm learning as I go, lol...ugh...

```
          Rough Hierarchical View
                                   ...Main Interface... <--Completed VB Windows Form
                                   .         .        .
Completed VB Windows Form--> Bard's Lounge   .     Hero's Lounge <--Completed VB Windows Form
                                             .
                                 ....Reference Library....
                                 .           .           .
                                 .           .           .                         
             Completed PDF--> Rules          .         Reference Materials  <--Completed PDF
                                             .        
                                             .        
            Completed VB Windows Form-->  Vendors
```

I have been researching saving as data type, but honestly, do not know what I do not know to find the correct answer. any help would be greatly appreciated. If you know of an actually useful Book for SQL, From Novice to advanced that would be amazing.